# How to refactor code and combine 4 methods in 1 in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have methods for Selenium test. Actions similar for each other.
I need to combine this 4 methods in 1 for better code-style, but do not have a lot of experience for this implementation.

```
public List<String> ticketId() {
        List<WebElement> ticketId = driver.findElements(ticketsIdLocator);
        List<String> ticketsIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ticketId.size(); i++) {
            ticketsIdList.add(ticketId.get(i).getText());
        }
        return ticketsIdList;
    }

public List<String> ticketTitle() {
    List<WebElement> ticketTitle = driver.findElements(ticketsTitleLocator);
    List<String> ticketTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ticketTitle.size(); i++) {
        ticketTitleList.add(ticketTitle.get(i).getText());
    }
    return ticketTitleList;
}

public List<String> ticketsAssignee() {
    List<WebElement> ticketsAssignee = driver.findElements(ticketsAssigneeLocator);
    List<String> ticketsAssigneeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ticketsAssignee.size(); i++) {
        ticketsAssigneeList.add(ticketsAssignee.get(i).getText());
    }
    return ticketsAssigneeList;
}

public List<String> ticketsStage() {
    List<WebElement> ticketsStage = driver.findElements(ticketsStageLocator);
    List<String> ticketsStageList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ticketsStage.size(); i++) {
        ticketsStageList.add(ticketsStage.get(i).getText());
    }
    return ticketsStageList;
}
```

Comment: If all the 4 locators extend the same base class/interface or are all of the same type, then create one method "getTickets" which takes the base class locator in parameter and work with it. If instead each locator is a different type and they have nothing in common, then pass a supplier of the value as parameter.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't supposed to be a code review service. Please read [ask].

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate place for this kind of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

some hints:

- the only difference in the locator. So, just pass it as a method param. Something like `findByLocator(ticketsStageLocator)`
- you can replace `for (int i=0.. , i++)` , with `for (WebElement el: ticketsStage)` or even with stream `driver.findElements(ticketsStageLocator).stream().map(...).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrite code, but still do not have solution

```
public class TicketsPage {
    public TicketsPage ticketColumns() {
        List<WebElement> ticketId = driver.findElements(ticketsIdLocator);
        List<WebElement> ticketTitle = driver.findElements(ticketsTitleLocator);

        List<String> ticketIdList = this.ticketsBase(ticketId);
        List<String> ticketTitleList = this.ticketsBase(ticketTitle);
    }
    public List<String> ticketsBase(List<WebElement> ticketElements) {
        List<String> ticketListBase = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ticketElements.size(); i++) {
            ticketListBase.add(ticketElements.get(i).getText());
        }
        return ticketListBase;
    }
}
```